# Trying to send an attachment with a webform

Tags: 6, webforms

Trying to send an attachment with a webform, but it isn't working.

I have MIME Mail installed, I have webform, I have attached a file to the node, and I have selected under the webform settings "include attachments".

However, when I have the webform send to my email, no attachment comes.

Why would this be?